# Why is glass a good conductor of heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, glass

AFAIK glass is insulator, it doesn't have free electrons. It's said metal is a good conductor of heat because it has free electrons, but glass doesn't have free electrons so why it is a good conductor of heat?

Comment: Glass is about 100 times more thermally insulating than metal, so this question really hinges purely on what you define as a "good" conductor of heat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two mechanism of thermal conductivity - free electrons and thermal phonons. The first mechanism can be prevalent in metals, the second one is important in dielectrics. I did not look up thermal conductivity of glass, but such excellent dielectric as diamond has higher thermal conductivity than any metal, as far as I know.

Comment: IIRC it has to do with the lattice structure. A Strong frame can be easily vibrated. Glass and diamond are both tetrahedral networks(?), so their mechanism would be the same. I guess.

Comment: glass by definition does not have a lattice structure Manis

Comment: @Manishearth: phonons are typically just lattice excitations, so we don't contradict each other. However, unlike diamond, glass typically does not have a regular lattice, so it is difficult to compare glass and diamond.

Comment: @akh Oh, whoops. I read "photons".

Answer (score 8):

Glass is a very **poor** heat conductor. It has one of the lowest possible heat conduction a solid (without air trapped in it) can possibly have, this is mostly due to its lack of ordered crystal structure. Since it's an insulator, the electronic contribution to the thermal conductivity is very small. However phonons can still carry heat, but unlike diamond which has a well ordered crystal structure, glass lacks such a structure. This favors anharmonic processes, i.e. phonon-phonon interactions such as umklapp processes which severely limit the thermal conductivity. See [this reference](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/CrystalStructure_Handout9_2.pdf) for instance.

One of the ultimate goals of finding good thermoelectric materials, is to achieve a glass-like thermal conductivity. In that case the thermal conductivity needs to be as small as possible. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08158) are [some](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0410) references.